# set date field using another date field

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want a textview (expiry date) to set automatically after i write the another textview(issue dATE) in my jsp page i am trying to do so using javascript but nothing happens .maybe there is some coding error.
please help !below is the code that i have posted..

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>MY SITE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="MyForm1" action="reaction2.jsp" method="POST">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td> Issue ID : </td>
                <td><input name="myText" value="" type="text" width="100"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Book Name : </td>
                <td><input name="myText1" value="" type="text" width="100"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Book ID : </td>
                <td><input name="myText2" value="" type="text" width="100"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Issue Date : </td>
                <td><input name="myText3" value="" type="date" width="100" id="txt1" onchange="setValue()"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td> Expiry Date : </td>
                <td><input name="myText4" value="" type="text" width="100" id="txt2" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Staff ID : </td>
                <td><input name="myText5" value="" type="text" width="100"/></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
            <p> <input type="submit" name="button3" value="Issue Book" /></p>
        </form>
        <script>
            function setValue()
                { 
                    var tt= document.getElementById('txt1').value;
                    var date=new date(tt);
                    var newdate=new date(date);
                    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 14 );
                    var dd = newdate.getDate();
                    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
                    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

                    var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
                    document.getElementById('txt2').value = someFormattedDate;
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's Date, not date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmutk1wc/1/)

Replace

```
var date = new date(tt);
```

to

```
var date = new Date(tt);
```

**JS**

```
function setValue() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(tt);
    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 14);
    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();    
    var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    document.getElementById('txt2').value = someFormattedDate;
}
```

Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information.

According to the docs, the constructors for `Date` are

> ```
> new Date();  
> new Date(value);  
> new Date(dateString);  
> new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
> ```

Comment: thnx buddy , it worked what a silly mistake i did !!

Comment: ya.. :D..Glad that it helped..:)